# Typescript how to add property to existing leaflet class definition

Tags: typescript, leaflet

In leaflet index.d.ts:

```
export namespace Icon {
    interface DefaultIconOptions extends BaseIconOptions {
        imagePath?: string;
    }

    class Default extends Icon<DefaultIconOptions> {
        static imagePath?: string;
        constructor(options?: DefaultIconOptions);
    }
}
```

I want to add property to the Default Class in my extra.d.ts

```
 class Default extends Icon<DefaultIconOptions> {
        extraProperty: any
    }
```

I have looked at (declaration-merging) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html ,but i have no idea how to merge existing class.

Is is possible to add/merge the property to existing class  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simply augment your class interface.

It should look like this:

```
declare namespace Icon {
  interface Default extends Icon<DefaultIconOptions> {
    extraProperty: any
  }
}
```